# Why does my iterator give wrong value?

Tags: ruby

I am expecting to print each number, not just one big value. This is my code:

```
i = 20
loop {
    i -= 1
    print i
    break if i <= 0
}
# >> 191817161514131211109876543210
```

I have tried:

- printing just `i`
- switching braces with `do` and `end`
- changing the value of `i`

Comment: You forgot to specify _why_ you think this output is wrong and what were you expecting to see.

Comment: Change `print i` to `puts i`

Comment: "not just one big incorrect value" - it's not one big value. It's your numbers printed really really close to each other.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhh christ... now I understand what the answer means too, apologies and thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using print which will print lines to the console without the \n at the end.

change `print` to `puts`.

Comment: @B001ᛦ OP is confused about what's going on.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes now I got him

Answer (score 2):

[`puts`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/puts) adds a new line after each argument passed to it (unless there's already a newline ending the arg).

[`print`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/puts) does not add a new line.

Therefore, you need to switch to `puts`:

```
i = 20
loop {
    i -= 1
    puts i
    break if i <= 0
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to using the following code:

```
i = 20
loop {
    i -= 1
    print "i\n"
    break if i <= 0
}
```

`\n` is the newline character:

> \n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.

Here's an example of passing multiple args to a `puts` statement, to really simplify your code:

```
puts *(0..20)
```

Or, in the reverse order you're using:

```
puts *19.downto(0)
```

This uses the `splat` operator to send the range as arguments to `puts`, giving you the output you're after,

Hope this helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Answer (score 0):

as you already got your solution, you need to replace `print` with `puts`. I am showing you an alternate solution to get the same output:

```
puts (0..20).to_a.reverse
```

OR

```
(0..20).to_a.reverse.each{|i| puts i}
```

**Output:**

```
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```